# jquery ui dialog not vertically centered after load

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog, center, vertical-alignment

I using jquery ui dialog with dynamic height. When it opens it’s centered, but when it loads the content it’s expanding toward the bottom of the page.

Here is my function:

```
$(this.document).ready(function () {
    $(".openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("<div></div>")
                    .addClass("dialog")
                    .attr("id", $(this)
                    .attr("dialog-id"))
                    .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: $(this).attr("dialog-title"),
                        close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                        modal: true,
                        width: $(this).attr("dialog-width"),
                        heith: 'auto',
                        resizable: false,
                        draggable: false,
                        show: 'scale',
                        hide: 'puff',
                        position: ['center', 'middle']
                    })
                    .load(this.href).dialog("open");
    });

    $(".close").live("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
    });
});
```

Comment: just an optimization, use "on" instead of "live".

Comment: @John Not really. I implemented the [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) solution. It works quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by setting autoOpen:false and creating the dialog content with my ajax call in the create method.  Once that returned, and the content created, I called open on the dialog.  Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Above ans not work for me.

```
$(document).live("ajaxStop", function (e) {
      $("#myDiagDiv").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```